# TableView with Image cell, need to improve my code

Tags: xcode, rss, tableview, thumbnails

I'm so frustrated with this code, It's been weeks and I can't find a solution to my problem.
My RSS application working great with some of the RSS's , it successfully pulling the image from the article into thumbnail to my table view. I figure out when the RSS XML type of file look in this structure, it's working great :

```
<item>
<title>" title going to be here "</title>
 <description>
    here is the description plus the image file <p><img src='http://img.mako.co.il/2014/05/20/maytal_7_a.jpg'/></p>
   </description>
  <link>
  here is going to be the link 
 </link>
```

my problem is that some RSS's don't have the image in the description, so I need to pull it off the article it self . 
my current cellForRowAtIndexPath code is this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {   
NewsItemCell *cell = (NewsItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:STORYBOARD_KEY__ID__NEWS_ITEM_TABLE_CELL];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[NewsItemCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MAIN_TABLE_CELL__NEWS_ITEM_CELL_WIDTH, MAIN_TABLE_CELL__NEWS_ITEM_CELL_HEIGHT)];
}

NewsItem *currentNewsItem = [self.newsItemsForSingleSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString* imageURL = currentNewsItem.imageUrl;

if ( [imageURL length] > 0 ) {
    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL: [NSURL  URLWithString: [imageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] ];
}
else {
    // placeholder if no image available
    //        cell.thumbnailImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green:0.4 blue:0.4 alpha:0.9];

    NSString * filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"placeholder_1.png"];
    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
}

cell.titleLabelView.text = currentNewsItem.title;
cell.newsItem = currentNewsItem;

return cell;
```

}

in other application I had , I used this pattern of code to grab the first image of the article and it's worked great :

```
 MWFeedItem *item = [listadoArticulos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // my Method to search and fetch the pictures to cell 
if (item) {
    NSString *htmlContent = item.content;
    NSString *imgSrc;

    // find match for image
    NSRange rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, [htmlContent length]);
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)" options:0 error:nil];

    if ([htmlContent length] > 0) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:htmlContent options:0 range:rangeOfString];

        if (match != NULL ) {
            NSString *imgUrl = [htmlContent substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
            NSLog(@"url: %@", imgUrl);

           NSLog(@"match %@", match);
            if ([[imgUrl lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"feedburner"].location == NSNotFound) {
             imgSrc = imgUrl;

                 [cell.myCellImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgSrc]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customItem30.png"]];
               }}}}
```

my question is, how can I combine both of them codes ? or maybe someone can think about other solution ( like a better code than mine ) . 
any help will be appreciated .

EDIT ** : Ohh I forgot to put the CellForRowAtIndex

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {   
NewsItemCell *cell = (NewsItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:STORYBOARD_KEY__ID__NEWS_ITEM_TABLE_CELL];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[NewsItemCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MAIN_TABLE_CELL__NEWS_ITEM_CELL_WIDTH, MAIN_TABLE_CELL__NEWS_ITEM_CELL_HEIGHT)];
}

NewsItem *currentNewsItem = [self.newsItemsForSingleSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString* imageURL = currentNewsItem.imageUrl;

if ( [imageURL length] > 0 ) {
    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL: [NSURL  URLWithString: [imageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] ];
}
else {
    // placeholder if no image available
    //        cell.thumbnailImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green:0.4 blue:0.4 alpha:0.9];

    NSString * filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"placeholder_1.png"];
    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
}

cell.titleLabelView.text = currentNewsItem.title;
cell.newsItem = currentNewsItem;

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First you can check whether the RSS feed contains any image url in the description tag using the regular expression (another application).If image is present,then only you have to create the News Item object and add that article.

```
    NSMutableArry * newsItemsForSingleSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     for(int i=0;i<listadoArticulos.count;i++)
      {
          MWFeedItem *item = [listadoArticulos objectAtIndex:i];

         // my Method to search and fetch the pictures to cell 
        if (item) {
              NSString *htmlContent = item.content;
              NSString *imgSrc;

            // find match for image
           NSRange rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, [htmlContent length]);
           NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)" options:0 error:nil];

            if ([htmlContent length] > 0) {
                   NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:htmlContent options:0 range:rangeOfString];

             if (match != NULL ) {
                         NSString *imgUrl = [htmlContent substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
                          NSLog(@"url: %@", imgUrl);

                          NSLog(@"match %@", match);
             if ([[imgUrl lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"feedburner"].location == NSNotFound) {
                      imgSrc = imgUrl;

                      NewsItem * currentNewsItem = [[NewsItem alloc]init];
                      currentNewsItem.imageUrl = imgSrc;
                      currentNewsItem.title = @"title";
                      currentNewsItem.Description = @"description";
                      [self.newsItemsForSingleSource addObject:currentNewsItem];
                      [currentNewsItem release];

           }}}}
  }
```

Then populate the NewsItem in the tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath.You have news which surely contains image.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I've Update my question and add the missing cellForRowAtIndex, it would be a great help if you guide me what code do I need to add .